# Angular: add class to span selector

Tags: css, angular

I have the below code, I want to add a class to a span selector, but I have this error

> Cannot read property 'classList' of null

```html
<th *ngFor="let column of columns;"
    <ng-container *ngIf="column?.sortable">
        <span [id]="'sort-'+column?.field" (click)="sortArray(column?.field)"></span>
    </ng-container>
</th>
```

```js
if (this.columns) {
   this.columns.forEach(column => {
       if (column.sortable) {
           const parent: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("sort-" + column.field);

           this.renderer.setElementClass(parent, "sorting_asc", true);
       }
   })
}
```

Comment: It means that document.getElementById("sort-" + column.field) is returning undefined and you're trying to set a class on undefined itself. Could you share more code of the component?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have overly complicated your code, You are using angular and I believe its not a good practice to access DOM elements using `document.getElementById()`.

For your code to work, you will need to ensure that the view has loaded before you can access the DOM elements. You need to move your code to the `AfterViewInit` life cycle hook.

Below is how I would refactor the code

```html
<th *ngFor="let column of columns;"
    <ng-container *ngIf="column?.sortable">
        <span [class.sorting_asc]="column?.sortable" (click)="sortArray(column?.field)"></span>
     </ng-container>
</th>
```

We simply bind to `[class.sorting_asc]="column?.sortable"` and let angular apply the classes for us